# How do I query mongodb with “like” on other column value

Tags: regex, mongodb

I am very much new for mongoDB. I have following records in my collection. In "myRegex" key I am storing Regex patterns.

```
db.Employee.find().pretty();;
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58256dadd110b0c95ee94c34"),
    "myRegex" : "^0091{6}$",
    "action" : "Test",
    "access" : "all"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58257ba5d110b0c95ee94c36"),
    "myRegex" : "^915(.*){5}$",
    "action" :"TestTest"
    "access" : "all"
}
```

Now I will pass one number and need to check that with which regex it is matching.
In mySQL, it is something like

```
SELECT * from Employee where '91123' like concat(myRegex,'%'); //Regext format will be different for MySQL, but this is just for understanding purpose.
```

So actual result is maximum matching regex with passed number.

I tried with below query but it is not working and gives an error :

```
db.Employee.find({'915623':exten});
```

Comment: Also try with below query still it returns no result.

    db.Employee.find({$where: "\"91123\".match(this.myRegex)"});


Now there is no errors but still I am not getting proper output.

Comment: Of course that query will not match any of the above two documents. However, the following will match the last doc: `db.Employee.find({ "$where": "\"91523\".match(this.myRegex)"});`

Comment: Welcome to the world of MongoDB. For people coming from a relational background, it may be a little shocking, but mongo does not offer much in terms of execution of programming logic in the database. You might be able to pull off such a stunt with map-reduce in mongo (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) but frankly, for me this is too much work to put into an answer. My main recommendation is: rethink your approach, and especially check again whether mongo suits your problem. You already have a solution using a relational db, why don't you just use it?

Comment: I got my problem. There was an issue in my Regex patterns. Still I am facing one issue regarding it.
Lets assume that I have 2 regex as "^91(.*)$" and "^915(.*)$". Now when I write 

    `db.Employee.find({ "$where": "\"91523\".match(this.myRegex)"});`

It will retun 2 results. But I want only single result as most matching regex. In this case it should return "^915(.*)$" record.

Comment: @Khushal , use findOne() for single result.

Comment: I don't want single result. I need the Longest match.  I used findOne() but in that case also it is returning the first matching result.

Comment: Make sure `^915(.*)$` is executed first.